# What is the difference between localhost and localnets in named configuration

Tags: dns, bind, bind9

Reading about acl statement in bind's ARM found the following:

localnets:

*"Matches any host on an IPv4 or IPv6 network for which the
system has an interface. When addresses are added or removed,
the localnets ACL element is updated to reflect the changes."*

"for which the system has an interface" - sound like a nosense.
I understand what network interface is, but don't understand aforementioned text.

**Could you please tell the meaning of the above quote, 
and what is the difference between *localhost* and *localnets*?**
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess `localhost` refer to one IP address which is by default `127.0.0.1`, but, `localnet` refer to every network that you have an IP address from it on interface on your machine.

For example, if you have two interfaces and every one have its IP from different network so `localnets` can match all networks.

```
eth0 ip 10.0.0.1    netmask 255.0.0.0
eth1 ip 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

So `localnets` match (`10.0.0.0\8, 192.168.0.0\24`).

Comment: You mean that localnets is the set of all addresses on machine's interfaces?

Comment: @BulatM. I have edited my question for more explanation